# how to bypass the instruction for antiDBI

Tags: dynamic-analysis, pintool

This instruction stops the execution of the pin code `jmp far 0x161061d, 0x33` ? how to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

This is the "Heaven's Gate" technique for switching from 32-bit to 64-bit code.  You'll need an updated version of Pin to proceed.

Comment: i use Pin 3.21. is there any way to bypass this instruction with the pin tools?